# How to save all styles when working with text inside an Excel cell using VBA

Tags: vba, excel, formatting

There are some problems when working with Excel using VBA.

If there is a cell containing several words, each of which has its own font, color, etc, if I'm stuffing some transformations above the line inside the cell, in this case I do the repl, the styles are lost for individual words; the entire string in the cell takes one style.

The question is: **How do I make a replacement for certain words, so that the rest of the words do not change styles?**

There is the option to go over the entire line and remember the styles of each character in the collection, and then after making the replacements, and other actions with the string, assign all the styles again, character-by-symbol, but this is long and costly, since there is a lot of text and lots of files.

Comment: Did you try to record this macro?